# How to auto fill from one value in a column to another column with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some work at the office that requires a macro that will autofill from one value in a column to another in another column. The trick is the values can occur at any cell in the column they are located in!

There are 31 rows in each column and the random value can be in any row or cell in the first column and the second value in any row for the next column. I tried the macro recorder but it seems to never work for any given cell and autofilling from one cell in column 1 to run into column 2.

example:

Comment: Your example is missing. Please provide the code what you already tried. Also your question is not very clear. Try to narrow it down to a specific point, because this is not a free code writing site. You may read [ask] too.

Comment: Recorded marco is unlikely going to help you on this, you may need to write a VBA macro programmatically based on random row name + random column number, then set the resulted row+column value to the new field.